Explode and parse json array of pyspark string column dataframe
I have PySpark DataFrame where column mappingresult have string format and and contains two json array in it
spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'server': {0: '3456gj',
  1: '56ujdn98',
  2: '56v95bd',
  3: 'barca6mw2k'},
'logev': {0: 'map.map',
  1: 'map.map',
  2: 'map.map',
  3: 'map.map'},
'status': {0: 'no prod',
  1: 'as rules',
  2: 'is found',
  3: 'not found'},
'mappingresult': {0: '[]',
  1: '[]',
  2: '[{"model":"s","com":"48b4-bfde","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]},{"model":"s","com":"76r-bfde","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]}]',               
  3: '[{"model":"s","com":"4827-44e9","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]},{"model":"s","com":"2222-44e9","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]}]'}})).show()




server
logev
status
mappingresult




3456gj
map.map
no prod
[]


56ujdn98
map.map
as rules
[]


56v95bd
map.map
is found
[{"model":"s","com":"48b4-bfde","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]},{"model":"s","com":"76r-bfde","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]}]


barca6mw2k
map.map
not found
[{"model":"s","com":"4827-44e9","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]},{"model":"s","com":"2222-44e9","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]}]



I need to increase the number of rows depending on the number of json arrys and parse the json into columns
here is the desired result



server
logev
status
mappingresult
model
com
ctid
params




3456gj
map.map
no prod
[]
s
48b4-bfde
987456
{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}


56ujdn98
map.map
as rules
[]
s
76r-bfde
987456
{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}


56v95bd
map.map
is found
[{"model":"s","com":"48b4-bfde","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]},{"model":"s","com":"76r-bfde","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]}]
s
4827-44e9
987456
{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}


barca6mw2k
map.map
not found
[{"model":"s","com":"4827-44e9","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]},{"model":"s","com":"2222-44e9","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]}]
s
2222-44e9
987456
{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}



I know, how to do it with string, but can't apply it to DataFrame
json_string = """
[{"model":"s","com":"48b4-bfde","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]},{"model":"s","com":"76r-bfde","ctid":987456,"params":[{"ID":"tr","val":"399.00"},{"IDp":"merch","val":"stackoverflow"}]}]
"""
spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json_string])).show(vertical=True)


Use from_json with schema with the required columns & inline for flattening array of values.
Schema - array<struct<model:string, com:string,ctid:bigint, params: array<map<string,string>>>>
df.selectExpr(
  "inline(
    from_json(
        mappingresult, 
        'array<struct<model:string, com:string,ctid:bigint, params: array<map<string,string>>>>'
     )
   )
")
.show(10, False)

+-----+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|model|com      |ctid  |params                                                           |
+-----+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|s    |4827-44e9|987456|[{ID -> tr, val -> 399.00}, {IDp -> merch, val -> stackoverflow}]|
|s    |2222-44e9|987456|[{ID -> tr, val -> 399.00}, {IDp -> merch, val -> stackoverflow}]|
+-----+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+


i have version 3.2.1, therefore i replace inline function with explode function. Generally, it works, but rows disappear where the attribute is empty and does not contain any data. How to save them also?

I think you are applying schema to data, if it is empty it should give null value to that particular column.
